# DataSnap com FireDac

Tags: delphi, datasnap, firedac

Numa aplicação com DataSnap, eu utilizava *SQLConnection*:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ConectaServidor : TUClasseServidorClient;
begin
 ConectaServidor := TUClasseServidorClient.Create(SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);
 try
     ShowMessage(ConectaServidor.mostrarTexto(Edit1.Text));
 finally
     ConectaServidor.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Porém, agora, preciso utilizar o *FDConnection* e preciso saber qual é o parâmetro dele equivalente ao *DBXConnection* do *SQLConnection*:

```
ConectaServidor := TUClasseServidorClient.Create(FDConnection1.parâmetro);
```

Comment: Experiemente passar o parametro "ConnectionName", exemplo = "ConectaServidor := TUClasseServidorClient.Create(FDConnection1.ConnectionName);"

Comment: [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(39): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Create' that can be called with these arguments

Comment: Não tenho experiência com esse componente.. tentei ajudar, outra coisa defeniu algum valor ao "ConnectionName", exemplo: "ConnectionName := xxx;"

Comment: Vê isto: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Defining_Connection_(FireDAC)

Comment: Não consegui...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terá de mudar a class TUClasseServidorClient para aceitar uma TFDConnection no Create.

São componentes muito diferentes e não existe correspondencia directa entre a class TDBXConnection e nenhuma propriedade da TFDConnection.